# Tensorflow/Numpy array data type

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a data set that looks like `[1, 'abcdthisisahash', 23.4]` (int, string, float).

I'm following the [abalone example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/estimators/abalone.py) and trying to load in a csv of the above dataset however I'm running into `ValueError: An initializer for variable dense/kernel of <dtype: 'string'> is required`. Its exiting on line `first_hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(features["x"], 10, activation=tf.nn.relu)`

I'm loading in the data `training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_without_header(
        filename='training.csv', target_dtype=np.float64, features_dtype=None)`

I have a feeling that array "dtype" is not properly defined. Setting the `features_dtype` to `None` makes both the first and second columns strings. The `target_dtype` is correct. How do I define the "dtype" properly? I cant find any info on having more than one datatype in a numpy array

Comment: A numpy `structured` array can have fields (not columns) with different dtypes.  `numpy` loaders like `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` can deduce this dtype from the data (with `dtype=None`).  I don't know what `tf` can do or required.

Comment: Thanks will give `loadtxt` or `genfromtxt` a shot